# RabbitMQ append exception details for messages going to DLQ

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have simple RabbitMQ configuration in Spring (not SpringBoot):

```
@Bean
public Queue queueTest() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable("test")
            .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", "myexchange")
            .withArgument("x-dead-letter-routing-key", "mykey")
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Queue queueTestDlq() {
    return new Queue("test.dlq", true);
}

@Bean
public Binding bindingTest(DirectExchange directExchange, Queue queueTest) {
    return BindingBuilder
            .bind(queueTest)
            .to(directExchange)
            .with("testkey");
}

@Bean
public Binding bindingTestDlq(DirectExchange directExchange, Queue queueTestDlq) {
    return BindingBuilder
            .bind(queueTestDlq)
            .to(directExchange)
            .with("testdlqkey");
}
```

Processing works properly and message is moved to DLQ in case of exception.

How can I append exception details (eg. message, stacktrace) to message headers for message going to DLQ?

Comment: "How can I append exception details"
You mean modify the message, this is not possible, you need to create another message and publish it.

Comment: Rather add some metadata than modify original message. Create another message is kind of workaround but not efficient.